# Why is a correlated subquery in this case so much faster than the max()-function?

Tags: sqlite

I have an SQLite database with a table with stocks (about 27000 rows), and a table with stock prices (about 60 mln rows). I need to get, for each stock, the date of the most recent stock price. Initially, I was using

```
SELECT stockID, MAX(PriceDate) AS MaxDate FROM StockPrices 
GROUP BY stockID
```

Explain query plan gives this:

```
"0" "0" "0" "SCAN TABLE StockPrices USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_StockPrices_1"
```

However, this takes about 21 seconds to run. Then I tried this one:

```
SELECT stockID, (SELECT PriceDate FROM StockPrices AS sp
                 WHERE s.stockID= sp.stockID
                 ORDER BY PriceDate DESC
                 ) AS MaxDate FROM Stocks AS s
```

Explain query plan gives this:

```
"0" "0" "0" "SCAN TABLE Stocks AS s USING COVERING INDEX Index_Stocks_CompanyID"
"0" "0" "0" "EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 1"
"1" "0" "0" "SEARCH TABLE StockPrices AS sp USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_StockPrices_1 (StockListingID=?)"
```

Now I get my results in 3 milliseconds.

This is a dramatic reduction in calculation time, and I'd like to better understand where this difference in performance comes from. 
I was under the impression that the max()-function would be pretty efficient, but obviously in certain cases much faster queries are possible. Both queries use the same covering index, so from the query plan I can't tell why one is so much faster.

These are the create statements used for the relevant tables and indices:

```
CREATE TABLE StockPrices (StockID INTEGER NOT NULL,PriceDate NUMERIC NOT NULL,PxClose NUMERIC NOT NULL,Volume INTEGER,Source TEXT,DateAdded NUMERIC DEFAULT (JulianDay(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)), PRIMARY KEY (StockID, PriceDate, PxClose, Volume))

CREATE TABLE Stocks (StockID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT ABORT,CompanyID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Companies (CompanyID),PrimaryListing INTEGER DEFAULT 0,Delisted INTEGER DEFAULT 0,ExchangeID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Exchanges (ExchangeID),CountryID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Countries (CountryID),IBKRSymbol TEXT,ISIN TEXT)
CREATE INDEX Index_StockListings_CompanyID ON StockListings (CompanyID)
```

Comment: You do have LIMIT 1 in the subquery, right?

Comment: Did you also try: `SELECT stockID, (SELECT MAX(PriceDate) FROM StockPrices AS sp WHERE s.stockID = sp.stockID) AS MaxDate FROM Stocks AS s`

Comment: I had, but removing it does not change the results, nor have a noticeable impact on speed. Since scalar subqueries only return a single row anyway, does it actually matter? (Apologies if that's a stupid question, I'm an economist by training, not a programmer)

Comment: I had not tried that one. That's even faster, at 0 ms, so thanks for that suggestion. But I still don't understand why that's so much faster than the first query.

Comment: Show your table and index definitions.